# Validate string contains a colon and numbers after it

Tags: javascript

I cannot seem to figure this out, and I have no experience with regex – is this even needed in this case?

I have a string in my js program which can look like this:

`192.158.21.10:1234` or `abcd123der2:12345`

I need to validate that this string contains a `:` and numbers after it

If it does, the program continues, if not if throws an error telling the user to input a valid string.

```
192.158.21.10:1234  -- Continue (validation successful)
192.158.21.10 -- Fail (incorrect input)
```

I know this is a easy idea, however I have been struggling to figure this out.

Comment: What regex patterns have you tried so far? You can always use online testers to learn regex for yourself...

Comment: ```/:\d+$/``` checks for a colon followed by one or more numbers. It does not require characters before the colon though. ```/^.+:\d+$/``` would check for any characters before the colon as well as the numbers after.

Comment: I have never used regex before, hence trying to figure out if this is necessary

Comment: @deeveeABC regex is never *necessary*, but it can sometimes be simpler.

Comment: Are you really just trying to check if a string contains a colon followed by numbers? Because from your examples it looks like checking for URL-s in `host:port` format, not just ordinary strings.

Comment: @pawel how would this change the answers? I tried to keep the question as simple as possible

Comment: @deeveeABC for example you could leverage the browser to parse URLs for you: `var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href ="//192.158.21.10:1234"; console.log( a.hostname ); console.log( a.port );`.

Comment: a.k.a. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Good idea, however in my program the user enters a URL, and I do not take it from anywhere else :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` - Start of the entry

`.+` - At least one character/number

`:` - Match semi-colon

`\d+` - At least one number

`$` - End of the entry

```js
var regex = /^.+:\d+$/;

console.log(regex.test("abcd123der2:12345")); //true
console.log(regex.test("192.158.21.10:123")); //true
console.log(regex.test("192.158.21.10:aa")); //false
console.log(regex.test("192.158.21.10123")); //false
console.log(regex.test(":123")); //false
console.log(regex.test("test:1morething")); //false
```

Comment: Yes, but `console.log(regex.test("test:1morething")); //true`

Comment: This is great. Thanks. But as @MarkAdelsberger mentioned, is there a way to make his example fail too?

Comment: @deeveeABC Updated

Comment: And now for a quick lesson in why regex is a leading cause of madness:  `console.log(regex.test("is:this:ok:too:123")); // true` -- if not replace the first `.` with `[^:]` ...

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Would you mind explaining what the reg ex does please? Or edit the answer if easier :) Works like a charm

Comment: Generally `[abc]` means "match an a, b, or c"; but if the first character inside the `[]` is a `^`, that means "match any character except those listed" -- e.g. `[^abc]` would match 'x', '1', ' '... anything but 'a', 'b', or 'c'.  So `[^:]` == "match anything but a :"; `[^:]+` == "match a string of one or more things that are not a :"; `^[^:]+:` == "match from the beginning of the string up to the 1st :, requiring that there's something before the 1st :"; `^[^.]+:\d+$` == match the whole string, requiring that it consist of some non-: characters, then :, then digits, and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say regex is "needed" in the sense that there are multiple ways to perform the check.  I would say regex is probably the easiest way, but it may or may not be the most efficient way (if this is a situation where the efficiency of the test should matter).

Anyway, `:\d+$` is a regex that may do what you want; it matches a colon, followed by 1 or more digits, followed by the end of the string.